# Baking custom Controller templates in CakePHP 3

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.7

Trying to bake my controllers from a custom template.

As per the [cookbook](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/bake/development.html#creating-a-bake-theme), I've baked a new plugin, and created the following directories:

- plugins/MyTemplate/src/Template
- plugins/MyTemplate/src/Template/Bake
- plugins/MyTemplate/src/Template/Bake/Controller
- plugins/MyTemplate/src/Template/Bake/View

In Bake/View I've created the basic CRUD templates, and they're baking fine. In Bake/Controller I've created a controller.twig file. It appears to be ignored. What am I missing?

Comment: What specific version of CakePHP and Bake are you using? Support for Twig templates was added in Bake 1.5.0, which requires CakePHP 3.5 or higher, but you've tagged the post with cakephp-3.0.

Comment: I'm using 3.7... there was no tag for this specific version